# how to add two restriction on datafetch in hibernate

Tags: hibernate

```
 public User findUser(String email) {
                User user = null;
                user = (User) sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class).add(Restrictions.eq("email", email)).uniqueResult();

                return user;

        }
```

Now I want to add one more restriction as if `active is 1` how can I do it. I am not finding any way that I could check for two restrictions
Please suggest
Romi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`add(Criteria)`](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html#add%28org.hibernate.criterion.Criterion%29) method returns itself (`this`) to allow for chaining.

```
public User findUser(String email) {
    User user = null;
    Criteria c = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createCriteria(User.class);

    //You can chain the add method, because it returns `this`.
    c = c.add(Restrictions.eq("email", email)).add(Restrictions.eq("active", 1));
    return (User) c.uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: nicholas.hauschild: Sorry, i dint get you :(